# How to save all changes in Backbone.js models and collection by click "Save" button?

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie, backbone-relational

I use things that are listed in the tags.
I have some model with many different relations.
The relations of model can be deleted or added(resource created) by user.

And I wanna save all changes in the main model and any relations update. By "clicking save button", that is, as one transaction at a time. It is desirable for one call to Tastypie.

How I can do that?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and post some code? It is too vague

Comment: It sounds like two questions: 1) you want to create a relational model schema with your Backbone models and 2) You want to persist the changes to your schema with one call to Tastypie. Please post more information.

Comment: @UziKilon Sure, that is a very simplified version of the code: http://pastebin.com/3kHEBngf

Comment: @Seebiscuit Yes, that's right. I have posted example with with pseudo-code http://pastebin.com/3kHEBngf

So I need to be able to remove the model or create new models (resources) and associate them with the `Product`.
And make saving it in one query.

Because on the backend part I keep a detailed history of all changes of the `Product`, and this should occur within a single query.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have very little experience with either technology. I can refer you to the product help pages, but I'm sure you've already read those.